# What programming languages have something like Haskell’s `newtype`

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, programming-languages, newtype

The Haskell programming language has a concept of `newtypes`: If I write `newtype Foo = Foo (Bar)`, then a new type `Foo` is created that is isomorphic to `Bar`, i.e. there are bijective conversions between the two. Properties of this construct are:

- The two types are completely separate (i.e. the compiler will not allow you to use one where the other is expected, without using the explicit conversions).
- They share the same representation. In particular, the conversion functions have a run-time cost of zero and return ”the same object” on the heap.
- Conversion is only possible between such types and cannot be mis-used, i.e. type safety is preserved.

What other programming languages provide this feature?

One example seems to be single-value-structs in C when used with record accessors/constructors only. Invalid candidates would be single-valued-structs in C when used with casts, as the casts are not checked by the compiler, or objects with a single member in Java, as these would not share the same representation.

Related questions: [Does F# have 'newtype' of Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425685/does-f-have-newtype-of-haskell) (No) and [Does D have 'newtype'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576580/does-d-have-newtype) (not any more).

Comment: I don't quite understand your argument of why single-valued C-structs don't qualify. Obviously if you use casts you loose type safety, but not if you just use the record accessors and constructors (like you do in Haskell as well). And any decent compiler will inline those to something equivalent to casts, just like GHC does with `newtype`.

Comment: leftroundabout: You have a point there; modified my question.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Your formulation "any decent compiler" leads me to assume that a C compiler is not required to do so?

Answer (score 11):

[Frege](https://github.com/Frege/frege) has this, though, unlike in Haskell there is no extra keyword. Instead, every product type with just one component is a newtype.

Example:

```
data Age = Age Int
```

Also, all langugaes that have nominal typing and allow to define a type in terms of another should have this feature. For example Oberon, Modula-2 or ADA. So after

```
type age = integer;      {* kindly forgive syntax errors *}
```

one couldn't confuse an age and some other quantity.

Comment: Thanks for the Frege pointer. About PASCAL: Does that really require explicit conversions? How would they look like?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Unfortunately, I am not quite sure anymore, it's been a while, you know. But I do know that one could even have something like `type age = 0 .. 130`. Maybe this helps: http://www2.informatik.uni-halle.de/lehre/pascal/sprache/pas_cast.html, essentially, it's explicit type cast.

Comment: Actuially it turns out that PASCAL did not have nominal typing. Yet Oberon, Modula-2 and ADA have it. So I will edit this.

Answer (score 8):

I believe Scala's [value classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/value-classes.html) satisfy these conditions.

For example:

```
case class Kelvin(k: Double) extends AnyVal
```

Edit: actually, I'm not sure that conversions have zero overhead in all cases. This [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html) describes some cases where allocation of objects on the heap is necessary, so I assume in those cases there would be some runtime overhead in accessing the underlying value from the object.

Comment: Can you create newtypes of anything, or just of primitive types?

Comment: It can by anything, not just primitive types.

Answer (score 8):

[Go](http://golang.org/doc/articles/laws_of_reflection.html) has this:

> If we declare
>
> ```
> type MyInt int
>
> var i int
> var j MyInt
> ```
>
> then i has type int and j has type MyInt. The variables i and j have distinct static types and, although they have the same underlying type, they cannot be assigned to one another without a conversion.

"The same underlying type" means that the representation in memory of a `MyInt` is exactly that of an `int`. Passing a `MyInt` to a function expecting an `int` is a compile-time error. The same is true for composite types, e.g. after

```
type foo struct { x int }
type bar struct { x int }
```

you can't pass a `bar` to a function expecting a `foo` ([test](http://play.golang.org/p/_FPFoBaF0X)).

Comment: Could you illustrate the type error that results from assigning an `int` to `j`? Also, are you cable to lift functions on `int` to `MyInt` (like numeric functions)?

Comment: @DonStewart: http://play.golang.org/p/IBGEdJyB5d; and no, there's no automatic "lifting". You have to do manual conversions. Built-ins such as `+` and `-`, which are not functions, will work, though.

Comment: @larsmans: How do you convert between MyInt and int in either direction? Is that conversion only possible with these types, or between any types (i.e. is it type safe even when conversions are used wrongly)?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner, here is an example: http://play.golang.org/p/Dj8HahN6ex it looks pretty much like function calls. But apparently it is possible to apply conversions to different types: http://play.golang.org/p/nmSVcQvD3a

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Can you cast between arbitrary types and hence cause runtime crashes? Then it would not qualify due to the third requirement.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: Go is type-safe and memory-safe and most conversions will trigger either compiler errors or panics (a restricted kind of exception). The only way to cast between arbitrary types is through the `unsafe` package, which is mostly used for interfacing to C code.

Answer (score 5):

Rust has always allowed you to make single-field types, but with the recently stabilized `repr(transparent)` attribute you can now be confident that the type created will have the exact data layout as the wrapped type, even across FFI and such.

```
#[repr(transparent)]
pub struct FooWrapper(Foo);
```

Answer (score 4):

[Mercury](http://www.mercurylang.org/) is a pure logic programming language, with a type system similar to Haskell's.

Evaluation in Mercury is strict rather than lazy, so there would be no *semantic* difference between Mercury's equivalents of `newtype` and `data`. Consequently any type which happens to have only one constructor with only one argument is represented identically to the type of that argument, but still treated as the same type; effectively "newtype" is a transparent optimisation in Mercury. Example:

```
:- type wrapped
    --->    foo(int)
    ;       bar(string).

:- type wrapper ---> wrapper(wrapped).

:- type synonym == wrapped.
```

The representation of `wrapper` will be identical to that of `wrapped` but is a distinct type, as opposed to `synonym` which is simply another name for the type `wrapped`.

Mercury uses tagged pointers in its representations.<sup>1</sup> Being strict and being allowed to have different representations for different types, Mercury generally tries to do away with boxing where possible. e.g.

- To refer to a value of an "enum-like" type (all nullary constructors) you don't need to point to any memory so you can use a whole word's worth of tag bits to say which constructor it is and inline that in the reference
- To reference a list you can use a tagged pointer to a cons cell (rather than a pointer to a structure which itself contains the information about whether it is nill or a cons cell)
- etc

The "newtype" optimization is really just one particular application of that general idea. The "wrapper" type doesn't need any memory cells allocated above what is already holding the "wrapped" type. And since it needs zero tag bits, it can also fit any tags in the reference to the "wrapped" type. Therefore the whole reference to the "wrapped" type can be inlined into the reference to the wrapper type, which ends up being indistinguishable at runtime.

---

<sup>1</sup> The details here may only apply to the low level C compilation grades. Mercury can also compile to "high level" C or to Java. There's obviously no bit fiddling going on in Java (though as far as I know the "newtype" optimization still applies), and I'm just less familiar with the implementation details in the high level C grades.

Comment: You say „it can“. Does it really? Also, how does conversion look like, and is it optimized to a noop? Is the converted value shared with the original value?

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Yes it really does, yes conversion is a no-op, and yes the converted value is shared. I opened by saying newtype **is** a transparent optimization. "It can" comes from the part of my post explaining that the effect of "newtype" is part of a related set of optimizations, and why they can be applied.